# Simple MD5 username in email validation url: is it safe?

Tags: email-validation

I'd be able to avoid creating a whole database for the validation or wasting some overhead on an otherwise wasted table in my current users table.

As far as I can tell it'd be a safe and clean solution. But I am very new to all of this and my question might even be silly and trite but I figured it would be safe to ask you experts first before committing a rather massive error.

The url would be something like this:
www.example.ex/validate/username/md5username

So my question is this: is this a good idea? would I even need to salt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a pure md5-hash, this would be a bad idea. As soon as a user see this scheme, he can validate new accounts without a valid mail-address.

At least, there must be some kind of salt for the md5-hash - preferable a new one for every user. Otherwise it would be [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Comment: Would using the registry date as a salt suffice? Or perhaps even md5ing the registration timestamp?

Comment: You have a (per user salt)[http://crackstationnet/hashing-security.htm], haven't you? I'm not an expert either but this should be enough. ( I mean md5(username+salt)). Using something the user is aware of seems not to be a good idea.

Comment: I'm using a bcrypt hash for my password, the salt is stored in the password. It's pretty sweet, and bcrypt is safer than old md5 and sha1. It doesn't translate well to urls, nor as a salt.